Issue While attempting to Configure build directory using Cmake
In an attempt to build JSON Fortran, I cloned the Github repo (please refer to the installation guide in the repo to get context) to a folder locally. Created a directory "b" within the repo folder.
After running cmake C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\HPC\json-fortran I get the following error.
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (enable_language):
      Running
    
       'nmake' '-?'
    
      failed with:
    
       no such file or directory
    
    
    CMake Error: CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


Also, I have installed a Fortran compiler supporting the Fortran-08 standard.
